# Verify all properties in firestore security rule match users claims

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need to ensure that a custom claim has properties which are true for all fields in a document before retrieving it. At first glance a function seems like the way to go, but as stated in the docs a security rules function may not contain loops, only a single return statement. How can I ensure that a a custom claim has all values within a document?

Example document:

```
{
            e_users: true,
            e_user_roles: true,
            e_user_groups: false,
            e_user_accounts: true
        };
```

Security rules:

```
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        
        function checkClaims() {
          return resource.data.List.filter((key) => { return auth.token[key] < resource.data[key] }).length > 0 ? false : true;
        }
    
        match /permissions/{permission} {
          allow read, write: if checkClaims();
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: please share a screenshot of your firestore document and tell which values are you expecting ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't iterate a list in security rules, so it's going to be hard to tell which values are false vs true. If the list is always fixed, you can of course compare them with a diff:

```
function checkClaims(dataRoles, authRoles) {
  return dataRoles.diff(authRoles).size() == 0
}

match /path/to/{docid} {
   allow read: if checkClaims(resource.data.roles, request.auth.token.roles);
}
```

This is of course problematic when you iterate on your app. Changing roles will break all existing auth tokens since the list of keys no longer match. Presumably that just requires clients reauthenticating to obtain the new claims if you push the updates in tandem. But still not a resilient answer.

One simple approach would be to discard the false roles and use an array to track the list of required roles. This allows you to perform a simple comparison as follows:

```
function checkClaims(dataRoles, authRoles) {
  return authRoles.hasAll(dataRoles);
}

match /path/to/{docid} {
   allow read: if checkClaims(resource.data.roles, request.auth.token.roles);
}
```

But this still doesn't scale elegantly since we're limited to 1000 characters. Additionally, what if we decide to change our mind later and add access levels instead of just flags? A more elegant approach might just be to store the roles assigned to a user id in the database as well, making changes much simpler to apply in the future.